# What is the difference between key_id and key_name in App Engine Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

AFAIK, there is only one difference: key_id must be int and key_name must be string. Is there any other practice limitations using key_id vs key_name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the only difference is the type (1 != '1').  Note that it impacts the ordering of results if you sort by key (as you would expect) - integers are sorted before strings.

Answer (score -1):

Key is a unique entity in all application like "ag5kZXZ-ZmVlbG1hcmtldHIRCxILU3RvY2tQcmljZXMYZgw"

Key name could be defined by you and apply only within the Entity Class
It could be like "john" or "mart"